# Execute Code on Every Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to execute some code on every request that stuffs data into ViewData. Currently I have a base controller class that all my controllers inherit from and I override OnActionExecuting and do it there.

My only concern with this approach is that whom ever creates a new controller will HAVE to inherit form the base class.

Is there a way to register something in the global.asax, like you would do with custom model binders, that would get ran every request? Kinda like a global action filter or something.

Comment: One of the first steps I take with every project is to add an empty controller base class to allow for code to be used by all controllers.  I got into the habit after reading MVC in Action, where that is one of the author's suggestions. I think that the approach you are currently taking is the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a base controller class (which I think is the best option for most scenarios), you could use a [custom action invoker](http://lostintangent.com/2008/07/03/aspnet-mvc-controlleractioninvoker-part-1/). I'd derive from the built-in action invoker and sprinkle in the extra stuff you need. You register the action invoker during app startup in global.asax and it can override OnActionExecuting / OnActionExecuted / OnResultExecuting / OnResultExecuted. You could, for example, use OnResultExecuting to add in some ViewData. At that point you'll know the action completed and also know the type of ActionResult.

Comment: This is what I was looking for and should work well. I already have a custom controller factory so I can turn sessions off, so adding this is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

In the `global.asax` , you can add a handler to `Application_BeginRequest` which gets run before every HTTP request. You can also create a [custom HTTP module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) to handle the same.

Comment: Yes, I know this. This is where all the stuff for MVC is being registered. There is nothing MVC specific in there though, but I'm guessing there is a way to add some object where I can tap into it. Like when you add a customer model binder, you do this in the global.asax file: "ModelBinders.Binders.Add( typeof( MyModelBinder, new MyModelBinder() );". Then when model binding occurs, your custom class gets called automatically, because you have it registered, which was done in the global.asax file.

Comment: Minor note: Accessing HttpContext.Current.Session from global.asax won't work as the Session object is not set at this point.