# Provide custom variables to every view in MVC (settings)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement a CMS and I would like to make some settings available to views.

These settings may be the web site's name, the company name and maybe some more complex items.

I would like these to be available on every view without using strongly typed Models, something like ViewData-ViewBag but without having to set it in every action.

I think that I have to create a `ControllerFactory` that will set the `ViewBag` on every `CreateController`.

What do you think that it's the best solution for this problem?

---

Possible duplication at [Execute Code on Every Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820970/execute-code-on-every-request)

Comment: Why dont you use partial views for this purpose. Thereby in just one page you can configure all your view information.

Comment: Do you mean to hardcode the settings? I would like the user to be able to change the settings himself using an admin page.

Comment: I think he talks about using a view inside a view. So u can display every common information on the inline view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own application controller and override `OnActionExecuting`. There you can initialize your own properties in Viewbag:

```
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // set your ViewBag.Settings here
    }
}
```

Create all of your controller classes derived from ApplicationController:

```
public class HomeController : ApplicationController { ... }
```

Now you can access `ViewBag.Settings` from all of your views without setting this property explicitly in each action.

Comment: This is a solution but then I would have to derive all Controllers from the ApplicationController and this is an extra step that I would wanted to skip.

Comment: No it's not wrong, but I would expect something that doesn't need maintenance (changing every new controller's base class to something). I think `ControllerActionInvoker` is better choice, you create it once and it collaborate with `Controller` class